# find a weak form to Navier equations

Tags: finite-element-method

I want to find a weak form to Navier equations and obtain a solution formulation .
I am interested in solving this problem using a finite element solver for which we need to introduce these equations in weak form.
Can anyone help me in this regard?
What is a higher-order continuity in the FEM approximation. This is challenge with the FEM which is based the Lagrange basis functions. To overcome the shortcomings, should we use the isogemetric analysis being based on the NURBS basis functions? How FEM cover this shortage for solving this type of equations?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Na84T.png

Thanks in advance for your guidance.